# Show table modified by executeUpdate()

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm doing a program where the user can do queries by hand and the results are showed in a jtable, for example:

```
userQuery= "DELETE FROM cds WHERE Nro_cd = 4;"
```

and I'm using this code

```
if (statement.execute(userQuery)){
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(userQuery);
    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Consulta Realizada");
    rs.close();
    }
    else {
        statement.executeUpdate(userQuery);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Modificacion Realizada");
    }
```

My problem is when I execute an update I don't get a resultset, is there anyway to do a select from the table that was updated?

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is when i execute an update i dont get a resultset ...

That is correct.  The most that you could get would be the number of rows affected (i.e. deleted, in your example)

> ... is there anyway to do a select from the table that was udpated?

I assume that you are asking if there is a way to select to find the rows that were deleted / updated in a previous statement.

No there isn't.

For a start, if rows have been deleted, they won't be there to be queried.  (Obviously!)

A regular database is not versioned.  You can't see what the state of the database was before an insert / update / delete.

---

If you need to know what records are deleted or updated, I think your best bet is to restructure your a code to do this:

1. Start transaction:
2. Select rows to be updated or deleted.
3. Read the resultset of the select and record what you need in the application ... or maybe in a temporary table.
4. Perform the updates / deletes
5. Commit transaction.

Now you can use the information you recorded in step 3.

---

See also:

- [Temporal databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database)
- [Temporal features in some database products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database#Implementations_in_notable_products)

Comment: what i need is to get the name of the last modified table so i can do a select on my program is anyway to do it? i was trying with databasemetadata but i get all tables. I dont care about the deleted data i care about the table that was modified someway to know the name. Dont forget the user writes the full query on textbox i need to know what table he modified to select it and show it

Comment: *"what i need is to get the name of the last modified table so i can do a select on my program is anyway to do it?"*.  AFAIK, not supported.  See the alternative strategy that I described.  Also, check to see if your database supports temporal features that might help.

Comment: so in short terms is far more easy if a look for a string match, like i do a seach for cds if it matches i do a select?

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is when i execute an update i dont get a resultset, is
>   there anyway to do a select from the table that was udpated?

You need to use `ResultSet` again to get the database records as shown below:

```
try{
  if (statement.execute(userQuery)){
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(userQuery);
    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Consulta Realizada");
    //rs.close(); //close in finally
    }
    else {
        statement.executeUpdate(userQuery);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cds");
        while(rs.next()) {
           //get data from resultset
        }
        //rs.close(); //close in finally
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Modificacion Realizada");
    }
 } catch(SQLException sqlexe) {
    //log exception
 } finally {
    //close resultset ad statements here
 }
```

Also, just note that, it is a best practice to close the `resultset` and `statement` objects inside the `finally` block.

Comment: can you explain me a bit, how is this giving back a result set if the userQuery is a "DELETE FROM cds WHERE Nro_cd = 4;" thats my problem update commands dont give any results

Comment: After doing executeUpdate(), you need to execute SELECT * FROM cds and fetch the resultset

Comment: ye thats the problem i have more than 1 table, user can do a delete from diferent tables and i dont find a way to know what table was modified